# Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement not able to download large files more than 2 gb from azure blob in c#

Tags: c#, azure

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleDownload
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            string accountName = "";
            string accountKey = "";
            string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accountKey;
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            await Download(account);
        }

        public static string GetSourcePath()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nProvide path for source:");
            string sourcePath = Console.ReadLine();

            return sourcePath;
        }

        public static CloudBlockBlob GetBlob(CloudStorageAccount account)
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            Console.WriteLine("\nProvide name of Blob container:");
            string containerName = Console.ReadLine();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("\nProvide name of new Blob:");
            string blobName = Console.ReadLine();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            return blob;
        }

        public static async Task Download(CloudStorageAccount account)
        {
            string path = @"D:\test.zip";
            Console.WriteLine("\nTransfer started...");

            DownloadOptions downloadOptions = new DownloadOptions();

            TransferCheckpoint checkpoint = null;
            SingleTransferContext transferContext = GetSingleTransferContext(checkpoint);

            CloudBlockBlob sourceObject = GetBlob(account);
            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 16;
            await TransferManager.DownloadAsync(sourceObject, path, null, transferContext, CancellationToken.None);

            Console.WriteLine("\nTransfer operation complete.");
        }

        public static SingleTransferContext GetSingleTransferContext(TransferCheckpoint checkpoint)
        {
            SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext(checkpoint);

            context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
            {
                Console.Write("\rBytes transferred: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
            });

            return context;
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to download big file from azure blob but using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement
nuget package currently I am getting different errors below mention while download big files
its working for small files but not working when files size in GBs

1. Timeout
2. Task canceled
3. The I/O Operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: **var task = TransferManager.DownloadAsync(.....); return task;** Later call **task.Wait();** before program exit such as after **Download();**

Comment: Thanks for answer I have tried with this approach but does not work

Answer (score 0):

current I fixed issue for download using azcopy.exe provided Microsoft

azcopy copy 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myTextFile.txt' 'C:\myDirectory\myTextFile.txt'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#:~:text=AzCopy%20is%20a%20command%2Dline,currently%20supported%20version%20of%20AzCopy.

Comment: here is Microsoft document download a copy exe and set the the blob and local folder path and execute exe it will download big file size